# ElasticSearch : Leader election by quorum?

Tags: elasticsearch, quorum

Elastic Search uses the quorum at two level

1. [Write consistency](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/distrib-write.html)
2. [New leader election when existing leader fails](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/_important_configuration_changes.html#_minimum_master_nodes)

I have a question how new leader election happens based on quorum under section `minimum_master_nodes` of this point 2 hyper link

> `Minimum_master_nodes`
>
> This setting tells Elasticsearch to not elect a master unless there
>   are enough master-eligible nodes available.  Only then will an
>   election take place.
>
> This setting should always be configured to a quorum (majority) of
>   your master-eligible nodes. A quorum is (number of master-eligible
>   nodes / 2) + 1.

My question here is why not any master node out of remaining eligible master node is selected ? Say I have two master node(M1 is current mastre, M2 is another master eligible node. M2 provides high availability). If M1 fails , M2 can be selected as new master.

So Why do we need quorum/voting to elect a new master  instead of just any master eligible node selection approach above ?

Comment: This is to avoid spit brain problem. This will help you understand: https://qbox.io/blog/split-brain-problem-elasticsearch

Comment: Also know that this master election process has been completely revamped in ES 7. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32006